# AWS: how to connect together 2 public subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-vpc

There's plenty of advice online on how to:

- connect **public** subnet to **private**
- connect 2 separate **VPCs** together

But I can't find anything on how to connect 2 public subnets within the same VPC. Currently I have them connected to the same Internet Gateway, but the resources in one don't talk to the other.

What's the right approach to solve this?

Comment: `public` means on the internet. they are connected via the internet. It's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: If they are in the same VPC they are "connected" by the route tables. They should be "connected" by default. If a resource in one can't connect to a resource in the other then you have a misconfigured route table, security group, or network ACL rule.

Comment: Amazon has a tool you can use to determine why your resources can't connect to each other: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html

Comment: @jordanm `public` means they have a route to an internet gateway so that they can access the internet directly. It does not mean they go out to the internet and back for internal communications.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All subnets (regardless of whether they are Public or Private) within the same Amazon VPC **can communicate with each other by default**.

Communication should be made via the **private IP address** of the resources, to ensure that the traffic stays *within* the VPC.

If this is not working, check:

- **Security Groups** on the resources, to ensure they are permitting access (Note: Merely putting resources in the 'same' Security Group does not mean that they can communicate with each other)
- **Network ACLs** should be left at their default "Allow All" setting. Only change NACLs if there is a very good reason to do so (eg creating a DMZ).

Comment: Thanks! Ended up being simler than I made it out to be... I'm new to this so thanks for clarifying.